# C++ Code Executes Only When the Program Is Run From The Terminal

Tags: c++, ogre

I have a strange bug that appears to happen only when the program isn't executed from the terminal. Here is my project: 
[https://github.com/elliotpotts/Troll/](http://github.com/elliotpotts/Troll/)
[https://github.com/elliotpotts/Troll/issues/2](http://github.com/elliotpotts/Troll/issues/2)

Look at the [Troll::State::keyPressed()](https://github.com/elliotpotts/Troll/blob/1a49afe8b2af21b9e7b0759c3703738c895328e3/src/State.cpp#L17) function. For some reason when I run the program from the terminal, everything is fine and the application exist but when I run it as a GUI program, the appliction doesn't exit. I can't think why. Thanks in advance, ell.

EDIT: Apologies for not adding Ogre tag and not posting the keyPressed function, here it is:

```
void Troll::State::keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent& event){
    if(event.key == OIS::KC_Q) {
        mCreator->stop();
    };
};
```

I have also tried adding file output to test it:

```
void Troll::State::keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent& event){
    std::cout << "Q was pressed" << std::endl;
    std::fstream file("log");
    file << "Q was pressed";
    file.close();
    if(event.key == OIS::KC_Q) {
        mCreator->stop();
    };
};
```

When run from the terminal, this works, otherwise, it does not. An added note, I do not have a functioning debugger at the moment which I am also trying to fix. Ell.

Comment: Sorry, can't help, but maybe adding **ogre** tag might draw attention from the right people.

Comment: Could you copy/paste `keyPressed()` definition here?

Comment: Perhaps the GUI framework has its own KeyEvent handler that gets the key?

Comment: Which GUI framework are you using? And how are you notifying key presses?

Comment: I am not using a GUI framework, only an input system. But I have recently found that the problem is caused by my IDE. Should I put that in an answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the IDE causing the problem, thanks for your help anyways, ell :)